# Using smarty to split a long list into multiple columns

Tags: php, smarty

i have this loop that i use for a menu navigation, however for lists bigger than 6 items i want to create the rest in a new list, would someone mind helping me on this:

```
{foreach from=$item1.$childs item="item2" name="item2"}
  {assign var="item_url2" value=$item2|fn_form_dropdown_object_link:$block.type}
  <li{if $item2.active || $item2|fn_check_is_active_menu_item:$block.type} class="cm-active"{/if}><a{if $item_url2} href="{$item_url2}"{/if}>{$item2.$name}</a></li>
{/foreach}
```

So output would be something like this:

If 6 or less items:

```
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
  <li>list item 6</li>
</ul>
```

If 6 or more

```
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
  <li>list item 6</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>list item 7</li>
  <li>list item 8</li>
  <li>list item 9</li>
  <li>list item 10</li>
  <li>list item 11</li>
  <li>list item 12</li>
</ul>
```

Of course, would like to loop every 6 items for example

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i managed to get a working solution to this, i found it very difficult to find online a solution for the requirement which i found strange as im sure its a common thing people are after if they are stuck but all the same please read on:

I tried the 2 methods as stated above by "ggonzalez" and "periklis" which i almost got working  but the markup it was producing was not correct and therefor breaking. In a nut shell it was wrapping the opening  tag around each list item and not closing but also not wrapping into lists of a certain amount i specified.

So after some playing around i came up with a solution that worked out just fine for me:

I found a smarty plugin called "split_row" which can be found here:

http://smarty.incutio.com/?page=split_row

I created the file: block.split_row.php and uploaded to my smarty plugin directory then added the following into my tpl file

```
{split_row count=8 from=$item1.$childs item="item2" name="item2"}
<ul>
    {foreach from=$item2 item="item2"}
    {assign var="item_url2" value=$item2|fn_form_dropdown_object_link:$block.type}                
    <li{if $item2.active || $item2|fn_check_is_active_menu_item:$block.type} class="cm-active"{/if}><a{if $item_url2} href="{$item_url2}"{/if}>{$item2.$name}</a></li>
    {/foreach}
</ul>
{/split_row}
```

I hope this helps anyone else looking for a similar solution to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.counter.tpl
And you can use it something like this:

```
{ foreach }
    { if counter % 6 == 0 }<ul>{ /if }
    <li></li>
    { if counter % 6 == 0 }</ul>{ /if }    
{ /foreach }
```

Comment: nice. you can also use `{$smarty.foreach.[foreachname].iteration}`

Comment: Above did not seem to work for me, ill give periklis solution a go - do i still need ot use counter?

Comment: Im a little lost on how to do achive this, can something do the solution for me with using the {$smarty.foreach.[foreachname].iteration} ?